# Rows coming extra in output xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an Input xml like this -

```
<SAMPLE>
<SAMPLE_ID>111</SAMPLE_ID>
<ROWS>
                    <ROW ROW_TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ROW_ID="1">                                               
                        <PRICE_PER_UNIT>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">1025.00</AMOUNT>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">949.07</AMOUNT>
                        </PRICE_PER_UNIT>
                        <ROW_TOTAL>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">1025.00</AMOUNT>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">949.07</AMOUNT>
                        </ROW_TOTAL>                            
                    </ROW>
                    <ROW ROW_TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ROW_ID="1">                                                       
                        <PRICE_PER_UNIT>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">67.00</AMOUNT>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">53.60</AMOUNT>
                        </PRICE_PER_UNIT>
                        <ROW_TOTAL>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">67.00</AMOUNT>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">53.60</AMOUNT>
                        </ROW_TOTAL>                            
                    </ROW>
                    <ROW ROW_TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ROW_ID="1">                                                       
                        <PRICE_PER_UNIT>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">3.00</AMOUNT>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">2.40</AMOUNT>
                        </PRICE_PER_UNIT>
                        <ROW_TOTAL>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">3.00</AMOUNT>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">2.40</AMOUNT>
                        </ROW_TOTAL>                            
                    </ROW>
                    <ROW ROW_TYPE="SUBTOTAL" ROW_ID="1">                                                        
                        <PRICE_PER_UNIT>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">1095.00</AMOUNT>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">0.00</AMOUNT>
                        </PRICE_PER_UNIT>
                        <ROW_TOTAL>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">1095.00</AMOUNT>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">0.00</AMOUNT>
                        </ROW_TOTAL>                            
                    </ROW>
                    <ROW ROW_TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ROW_ID="2">                                                       
                        <PRICE_PER_UNIT>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">315.00</AMOUNT>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">291.67</AMOUNT>
                        </PRICE_PER_UNIT>
                        <ROW_TOTAL>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">630.00</AMOUNT>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">583.33</AMOUNT>
                        </ROW_TOTAL>                            
                    </ROW>
                    <ROW ROW_TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ROW_ID="2">                                                       
                        <PRICE_PER_UNIT>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">30.00</AMOUNT>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">24.00</AMOUNT>
                        </PRICE_PER_UNIT>
                        <ROW_TOTAL>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">60.00</AMOUNT>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">48.00</AMOUNT>
                        </ROW_TOTAL>                            
                    </ROW>
                    <ROW ROW_TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ROW_ID="2">                           
                        <PRICE_PER_UNIT>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">10.00</AMOUNT>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">8.00</AMOUNT>
                        </PRICE_PER_UNIT>
                        <ROW_TOTAL>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">20.00</AMOUNT>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">16.00</AMOUNT>
                        </ROW_TOTAL>                            
                    </ROW>
                    <ROW ROW_TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ROW_ID="2">                           
                        <PRICE_PER_UNIT>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">175.00</AMOUNT>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">140.00</AMOUNT>
                        </PRICE_PER_UNIT>
                        <ROW_TOTAL>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">350.00</AMOUNT>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">280.00</AMOUNT>
                        </ROW_TOTAL>                            
                    </ROW>
                    <ROW ROW_TYPE="SUBTOTAL" ROW_ID="2">                            
                        <PRICE_PER_UNIT>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">530.00</AMOUNT>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">0.00</AMOUNT>
                        </PRICE_PER_UNIT>
                        <ROW_TOTAL>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">1060.00</AMOUNT>
                            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">0.00</AMOUNT>
                        </ROW_TOTAL>                            
                    </ROW>                  
                </ROWS>
```

My conversion looks like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:key name="kRowById" match="ROW[not(@ROW_TYPE='SUBTOTAL' or @ROW_TYPE='MAIN' or @ROW_TYPE='COMMENT')]" use="@ROW_ID"/>
    <xsl:template match="ROW[not(@ROW_TYPE='SPECIFICATION')]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('kRowById', @ROW_ID)"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My output structure is coming correct but the only issue is, this logic is adding extra repeating ROWS in the output xml.
Which are not required. Any suggestions on this.

Expected Output -

```
<SAMPLE>
    <ROW ROW_TYPE="SUBTOTAL" ROW_ID="1">        
        <PRICE_PER_UNIT>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">1095.00</AMOUNT>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">0.00</AMOUNT>
        </PRICE_PER_UNIT>
        <ROW_TOTAL>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">1095.00</AMOUNT>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">0.00</AMOUNT>
        </ROW_TOTAL>        
    </ROW>
    <ROW ROW_TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ROW_ID="1">       
        <PRICE_PER_UNIT>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">1025.00</AMOUNT>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">949.07</AMOUNT>
        </PRICE_PER_UNIT>
        <ROW_TOTAL>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">1025.00</AMOUNT>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">949.07</AMOUNT>
        </ROW_TOTAL>        
    </ROW>
    <ROW ROW_TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ROW_ID="1">       
        <PRICE_PER_UNIT>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">67.00</AMOUNT>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">53.60</AMOUNT>
        </PRICE_PER_UNIT>
        <ROW_TOTAL>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">67.00</AMOUNT>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">53.60</AMOUNT>
        </ROW_TOTAL>        
    </ROW>
    <ROW ROW_TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ROW_ID="1">       
        <PRICE_PER_UNIT>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">3.00</AMOUNT>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">2.40</AMOUNT>
        </PRICE_PER_UNIT>
        <ROW_TOTAL>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">3.00</AMOUNT>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">2.40</AMOUNT>
        </ROW_TOTAL>        
    </ROW>
    <ROW ROW_TYPE="SUBTOTAL" ROW_ID="2">        
        <PRICE_PER_UNIT>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">530.00</AMOUNT>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">0.00</AMOUNT>
        </PRICE_PER_UNIT>
        <ROW_TOTAL>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">1060.00</AMOUNT>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">0.00</AMOUNT>
        </ROW_TOTAL>        
    </ROW>
    <ROW ROW_TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ROW_ID="2">       
        <PRICE_PER_UNIT>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">315.00</AMOUNT>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">291.67</AMOUNT>
        </PRICE_PER_UNIT>
        <ROW_TOTAL>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">630.00</AMOUNT>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">583.33</AMOUNT>
        </ROW_TOTAL>        
    </ROW>
    <ROW ROW_TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ROW_ID="2">       
        <PRICE_PER_UNIT>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">30.00</AMOUNT>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">24.00</AMOUNT>
        </PRICE_PER_UNIT>
        <ROW_TOTAL>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">60.00</AMOUNT>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">48.00</AMOUNT>
        </ROW_TOTAL>        
    </ROW>
    <ROW ROW_TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ROW_ID="2">       
        <PRICE_PER_UNIT>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">10.00</AMOUNT>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">8.00</AMOUNT>
        </PRICE_PER_UNIT>
        <ROW_TOTAL>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">20.00</AMOUNT>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">16.00</AMOUNT>
        </ROW_TOTAL>        
    </ROW>
    <ROW ROW_TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ROW_ID="2">       
        <PRICE_PER_UNIT>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">175.00</AMOUNT>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">140.00</AMOUNT>
        </PRICE_PER_UNIT>
        <ROW_TOTAL>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="INCLUDED">350.00</AMOUNT>
            <AMOUNT SIGN="+" VAT="EXCLUDED">280.00</AMOUNT>
        </ROW_TOTAL>        
    </ROW>
</SAMPLE>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to edit your question to show your expected output, otherwise it is not clear exactly what rows you don't want to see. Thanks!

Comment: As far as I can see, your expected output matches what is produces by the XSLT in your question.....

Comment: From my xslt conversion, the ROW_TYPE="SPECIFICATION" rows are coming extra. If ROW_ID="1" contains 3 times ROW_TYPE="SPECIFICATION" , then my conversion result comes with 9 times. please check again.

Comment: You were right, the logic is working fine. But I have now edited the Input XML with root tag as SAMPLE and its SAMPLE_ID as 111 and then ROWS for it. Now if I have multiple samples, with SAMPLE_ID 222, 333 with similar ROWS data then this logic repeats the lines in output. How it will working with multiple SAMPLES?

Comment: Are you saying your input has multiple SAMLPLE elements, but you only want to see one SAMPLE in the output? It might help if you edited your example to show multiple SAMPLE elements. It would also be easier to help if you could make your XML samples a bit smaller. Perhaps remove some of the child elements, like ARTICLE. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, my Input has multiple SAMPLE elements with similar ROW data. And in Output I want the multiple SAMPLE elements again with similar ROW data. The expected output is detailed above. I have shown here with one SAMPLE element but for both Input & Output, i need multiple SAMPLE elements with the defined structure.

Answer (score 0):

Because your question has only one "SAMPLE" element, it is not entirely clear how you want it to look with multiple "SAMPLE" elements, but I am thinking you probably need to extend your xsl:key to include the SAMPLE_ID element.

```
<xsl:key name="kRowById" 
         match="ROW[not(@ROW_TYPE='SUBTOTAL' or @ROW_TYPE='MAIN' or @ROW_TYPE='COMMENT')]"
         use="concat(@ROW_ID, '|', ../../SAMPLE_ID)"/>
```

So, the key uses both ROW_ID and SAMPLE_ID. Note the use of the `|` character as a delimiter; it can be any character here, just as long as it does not appear in ROW_ID or SAMPLE_ID.

Then, you use the same key in your existing xsl:copy when getting the ROW elements for a SAMPLE.

```
<xsl:copy-of select="key('kRowById', concat(@ROW_ID, '|', ../../SAMPLE_ID))"/>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="kRowById" match="ROW[not(@ROW_TYPE='SUBTOTAL' or @ROW_TYPE='MAIN' or @ROW_TYPE='COMMENT')]" use="concat(@ROW_ID, '|', ../../SAMPLE_ID)"/>

    <xsl:template match="ROW[not(@ROW_TYPE='SPECIFICATION')]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('kRowById', concat(@ROW_ID, '|', ../../SAMPLE_ID))"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

    <xsl:template match="SAMPLE">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```